# Looking for Convenience Factory To Create GroovyObjectSupport Instances

Tags: java, groovy, metaclass

I want to be able to create instances of GroovyObjectSupport (in Java) that wrap simple pojos (of any class) on the fly. I was hoping to find something that examined the class type of a provided pojo and implemented the GroovyObjectSupport constructs in AOP/ByteCode, but I'm open to any good ideas.

Ideally it would look something like this:

```
GroovyObjectSupport gos = GroovyObjectSupportFactory.generate(myPojo);
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you get away with wrapping it in a Proxy?

ie:  you can do this:

```
import groovy.util.Proxy

...

String s = new String( "tim" )
Proxy p = new Proxy().wrap( s )

...
// Then in Groovy, you can do:

println p.length() // 3
println p.adaptee.class.name // "java.lang.String"
```

The `Proxy` class extends `GroovyObjectSupport`

Comment: Thanks Tim; I poked around with Proxy and it is exactly what I was looking for. This actually seemed to work the best:   ProxyGenerator.INSTANCE.instantiateDelegate(myPojo);